# Displaying Admob Interstitial Ads without initialize Publisher ID

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I have an android app published in Play Store and displaying Interstitial Ads.

I have a concern regarding this:
In my script, I only set the Interstitial ID using `setAdUnitId()` without initializing Publisher ID `MobileAds.initialize(this,<Publisher_ID>)`.
Is it okay to do this?
Are there any disadvantages not initialize our publisher ID?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [official Unity Plugin](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity) to implement the Mobile Ads SDK, then, as stated in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/HgmqbHFz-Hc), just using your Ad Unit ID should be fine.